# PCI Compliant service to store credit card info - [NON-US Company]

Tags: api, payment-gateway, credit-card, pci-dss

I am developing a website that will allow customers to pay with credit cards. I live in Uruguay, so I can't apply for a normal merchant account like Authorize.net, Braintree, etc. So I can't use the functionality they have to store credit cards to make recurring charges.

Anyone known a credit card processor/gateway that offers this functionality that allows to store credit card info and access them (Not seeing the credit card info, just a token or an ID) via an API to charge them and that accept NON-US companies? I know 2checkout but they don't have recurring payments functionality :(

I have Googled for days without luck, and maybe someone have a good tip.

Thank you very much for your time!

All the best,
Andres Montalban

Comment: I damn hope there is no system that stores credit card details that can be fetched with an API..

Comment: Yes true... Silly me... The problem is that the only gateway I know it works with international customers is 2Checkout. Authorize.net is great and they have a service called CIM which will be very easy to use but can't apply :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use the paypal API, and instead of storing the users credit card, store their paypal ID, then just bill the paypal account with the API. Their paypal account will let them enter a credit card to back their transactions.
See here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I wasn't aware of this. I will have it in mind as last resource because I want that the signup/payment process to be as simple and fast as possible. Also I want to retain customers in my website.

Comment: Finally I will have to use PayPal because couldn't find one that allows non-us/non-uk companies and 2Checkout didn't accept the service I want to offer (IT support). Thank you very much for your answer!